# How to identify recipient/sender user in Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to implement a private messaging function within my app, and the one thing that is holding me back is the simple fact that I cannot seem to wrap my head around identifying the recipientUser.

How should I identify the recipientUser through their object id, if the sender is the PFUser.currentUser?

How should my query be formatted? 
This is what I have in my MessageFeedViewController:

```
func retrieveMessages() {

        // create PFQuery
        var msgQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")
        msgQuery.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        msgQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


            for msgObject in objects! {

                self.messageContent.append(msgObject["content"] as! String)



            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.messagesTableView.reloadData()

            }
        }

    }
```

Not too brutal guys... I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Try below thing,

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "XXXXXXXX")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Your user object.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use the private class name, use the provided API to create the query. Also, if you have the object id you should just get rather than query for it.